# Console output when running Junit tests with ParallelComputer

Tags: java, junit

I want to run the Junit tests in parallel. I am running into the following problem

These tests are developed by other teams and there are about 2500 test suites. The tests and the test framework have static variables all over the place. They have been written so that they work fine when they are run one suite at a time. They do not even complete running when I construct a suite of those tests suites and run them.

In order to get around this problem, I have my own test runner that loads the test suite by a different class loader(a group of tests at a time). I do that in multiple threads and call the run method of JunitCore from each of these threads. This works fine. The problem with this approach is that the console output is mixed.

I am looking for a solution to this problem so that I can separate the console output for the test suite and redirect them into a file.

Here is one potential solution I am considering. I could load the classes with different classloader and pass the array of the "Class" objects of those classes into JunitCore [runClasses](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#runClasses(org.junit.runner.Computer,%20java.lang.Class...)) with an instance of [ParallelComputer](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/ParallelComputer.html).

Has anybody tried running test suites using ParallelComputer? How is the console output handled?

Comment: Did you try it to see? Can you provide a different output file to each test thread? What does it mean to run the tests in parallel but somehow serialize/separate the output to a single console?  It's not clear what you are asking, and you haven't provided nearly enough context or evidence of research.

Comment: I have not tried yet. The tests and the framework output to stdout (they may be using directly System.out.println or through some sort of logger). Regardless of how that is done, I see a lot of information on the console when the test runs. When I tried to run the tests in threads, all that output is mixed. I want to separate the console output per thread. ParallelComputer is supposed to run the tests in parallel. But I do not know how the console output is handled. My question was if anybody has tried that and if so, how is the System.out.println output handled. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I  see that when you try running the JUnit tests using ParallelComputer, the std out is all mixed up. I was expecting that but I tried with a small program.

My program is below

```
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.experimental.*;

public class ParallelComputerTest {  

public static void main(String[] args) {      
Class[] cls={ParallelTest1.class,ParallelTest2.class };  

//Parallel among classes  
JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.classes(), cls);      
}  

public static class ParallelTest1{  
@Test public void a1(){
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 5) {
    System.out.println("a1");
    count++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
    }

}  
@Test public void b1(){
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 5) {
    System.out.println("b1");
    count++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
    }
}  
}  
public static class ParallelTest2{  
@Test public void a(){
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 5) {
    System.out.println("a2");
    count++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
    }
}  
@Test public void b(){
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 5) {
    System.out.println("b2");
    count++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
    }
}  
}  
}
```

The output is like this

```
a2
a1
a2
a1
a2
a1
a1
a2
a1
a2
b1
b2
b1
b2
b1
b2
b1
b2
b1
b2
```

I am looking for a way to demultiplex the stdout.